# Multiple Column Duplicate Entry Check MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm aware that you can create a unique column in your MySQL table, but I'm actually looking to compare TWO columns.

So if I had records like:

```
Time          User       Table
10:00pm       Fred       29
11:00am       Bob        33
```

I COULD insert a new record with the `time 10:00pm` and `table 33` but not `10:00pm table 29`.

I know I could run a query and then nullify my ability to insert a new record if I had results from that query based on comparing those two fields, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution wherein I can get a duplicate entry error from MySQL on the INSERT and save myself a few lines of code.

Comment: You are essentially looking for a multi-column constraint.

Comment: I wish I knew those words 2 hours ago.  I googled that and came to this exact conclusion on this site.  At least people like me who haven't figured it out will have a matching query now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a unique index that incorporates both columns:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_time_and_table ON reservations (`Time`, `Table`);
```

This will block any inserts for the same pairing provided both values are not `NULL`. Having a `NULL` value side-steps the unique checking.

You're also using reserved SQL keywords for your column names which you might want to change.

Comment: my sql keywords were changed in this question to protect the innocent.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a composite unique constraint across both columns:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD UNIQUE(`Time`, `Table`);
```

Now any rows attempting to be added that have matching values will force MySQL to throw an error, which you can test for in your app.

Answer (score 2):

Create an unique index based on the columns you want to be unique:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON table_name ( column1, column2,...);
```